import specific columns from one workbook to another from matching header with vba
i have two excel workbooks with same header names in them, I am looking for solution in which I can import/copy columns based on their header name from one excel workbook to another excel workbook using macro/VBA code.
EX:
Source WB



Column A
Column B
Column C
Column D




Cell 1
Cell 2
Cell 3
Cell 4


Cell 5
Cell 6
Cell 7
Cell 8



Target WB



Column B
Column D




Cell x
Cell y


Cell x
Cell y



Output should be updating Target WB with data of columns from source WB as below



Column B
Column D




Cell 2
Cell 4


Cell 6
Cell 8



I have tried below code but it is not updating final workbook.
Sub Pull_finalise_columns()
    On Error Resume Next
    Const Adopenstatic = 3
    Const adlockoptimistic = 3
    Const adcmdtext = &H1
    
    Dim conn As Object
    Dim sf As Object            'setting up source file
    Dim filename As String
    Dim filepath As String

    filepath = "D:\"           'location where source file is located
    filename = "Test.xlsm"           'name of sourcefile
    
    Set conn = CreateObject("adodb.connection")
    Set rs = CreateObject("adodb.recordset")
    
    conn.Open "provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" & _
                "data source=" & filepath & ";" & _
                "extended properties=""Excel 16.0; HDR=yes"""
    
    sf.Open "select[File Name],[$business Name],[$Business Description],[Personal Identifier Special Category],[Data Treatment],[Personal Identifier Type],[Primary Key]," _
             & [Security Classification Candidate], [PCI-DSS], [Pi] _
             & [" & filename & "], conn, Adopenstatic, adlockoptimistic, adcmdtext
                
    Worksheets("sheet1").Range("a1").CopyFromRecordset sf
    sf.Close
    conn.Close
End Sub


On Error Resume Next prevents you from seeing the errors in your code.

First big kicker to your expectation can be summed up by this lack of qualification:  Worksheets("sheet1").  You will want to set sourceWorkbook and set destinationWorkbook to keep track of what is being utilized.  You could even further set the sheets to make with statements simpler, or destWS.range().value = srcWS.range().value

There's no from in your SQL and the path to the source doesn't include the file name.

Import Data by Matching Headers
Assumptions

The data will be imported only if the source workbook is closed when it will be closed, or it is open but saved when it will remain open (whether saved or not).
The destination sheet is in the workbook containing this code (ThisWorkbook).
The data in both sheets is adjacent and starts in A1 with one row of headers.

The Code

The code is currently set up to clear any existing data in the destination sheet. If you want to append the data, set DST_CLEAR_EXISTING_DATA to False.
The code is also currently set up to copy only values. If you also want to copy formats, set COPY_VALUES_ONLY to False.

Sub ImportDataByMatchingHeaders()
    
    ' Implement an error-handling routine.
    
    ' Declare constants and variables used in the error-handling routine.
    Const PROC_TITLE As String = "Import Data by Matching Headers"
    Dim swb As Workbook, WasSourceFileOpen As Boolean
    
    ' Start error-handling routine.
    On Error GoTo ClearError

    ' Define constants.
    
    Const SRC_FOLDER_PATH As String = "C:\Test"
    Const SRC_FILE_NAME As String = "Test.xlsx"
    Const SRC_SHEET_ID As Variant = "Sheet1"

    Const DST_SHEET_ID As Variant = "Sheet1" ' in 'ThisWorkbook'
    Const DST_DISALLOW_BLANK_HEADERS As Boolean = False
    Const DST_CLEAR_EXISTING_DATA As Boolean = True
    
    Const COPY_VALUES_ONLY As Boolean = True ' copying values is more efficient
    
    ' Reference the destination workbook.
    
    Dim dwb As Workbook: Set dwb = ThisWorkbook ' workbook containing this code
    
    ' Reference the destination worksheet.
    
    Dim dws As Worksheet
    
    On Error Resume Next ' prevent error when the destination sheet does't exist
        Set dws = dwb.Sheets(DST_SHEET_ID)
    On Error GoTo ClearError
    
    If dws Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "There is no worksheet named """ & DST_SHEET_ID _
            & """ in the workbook containing the code """ & dwb.Name & """!", _
            vbExclamation, PROC_TITLE
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    ' Reference the destination header row and first row ranges.
    
    Dim dhrg As Range, dfrg As Range, dColumnsCount As Long
    
    With dws.Range("A1").CurrentRegion
        Set dhrg = .Rows(1)
        If DST_DISALLOW_BLANK_HEADERS Then
            If Application.CountBlank(dhrg) > 0 Then
                MsgBox "There are blank headers in worksheet """ & dws.Name _
                    & """ of workbook """ & dwb.Name & """!", _
                    vbExclamation, PROC_TITLE
                Exit Sub
            End If
        End If
        dColumnsCount = dhrg.Columns.Count
        If DST_CLEAR_EXISTING_DATA Then
            .Resize(dws.Rows.Count - .Row).Offset(1).Clear
            Set dfrg = .Rows(1).Offset(1)
        Else
            Set dfrg = .Rows(1).Offset(.Rows.Count)
        End If
    End With
    
    ' Check if the source file doesn't exist.
    
    Dim sFolderPath As String: sFolderPath = SRC_FOLDER_PATH
    Dim pSep As String: pSep = Application.PathSeparator
    
    If Right(sFolderPath, Len(pSep)) <> pSep Then
        sFolderPath = sFolderPath & pSep
    End If
    
    If Len(Dir(sFolderPath, vbDirectory)) = 0 Then
        MsgBox "The path """ & sFolderPath & """ doesn't exist!", _
            vbExclamation, PROC_TITLE
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    Dim sFilePath As String: sFilePath = sFolderPath & SRC_FILE_NAME
    
    If Len(Dir(sFilePath)) = 0 Then
        MsgBox "The file """ & sFilePath & """ doesn't exist!", _
            vbExclamation, PROC_TITLE
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    ' Open and reference the source file.
    
    ' Attempt to reference the source workbook.
    On Error Resume Next ' prevent error when the source file is not open
        Set swb = Workbooks(SRC_FILE_NAME)
    On Error GoTo ClearError
    
    ' Check whether the source file is open.
    If swb Is Nothing Then ' the source file is not open
        Application.DisplayAlerts = False
        On Error Resume Next
            Set swb = Workbooks.Open( _
                Filename:=sFilePath, _
                ReadOnly:=True)
        On Error GoTo ClearError
        Application.DisplayAlerts = True
        If swb Is Nothing Then
            MsgBox "Could not open the file """ & sFilePath & """!", _
                vbExclamation, PROC_TITLE
            Exit Sub
        End If
    Else ' a file with the same name is open; is it the source file?
        If StrComp(swb.FullName, sFilePath, vbTextCompare) = 0 Then ' Yes!
            If swb.Saved = True Then ' only continue if it is saved
                WasSourceFileOpen = True
            Else ' don't continue if it is not saved
                MsgBox "The file """ & swb.Name _
                    & """ is already open but it is not saved!", _
                    vbExclamation, PROC_TITLE
                Exit Sub
            End If
        Else ' No, another file with the same name is open.
            MsgBox "A different file named """ & swb.Name _
                & """ located at """ & swb.Path & """ is open!", _
                vbExclamation, PROC_TITLE
            Exit Sub
        End If
    End If
    
    ' Reference the source worksheet.
    
    Dim sws As Worksheet
    
    ' Attempt to reference the source worksheet.
    On Error Resume Next ' prevent error when the source sheet doesn't exist
        Set sws = swb.Sheets(SRC_SHEET_ID)
    On Error GoTo ClearError
    
    ' Check if the source worksheet doesn't exist.
    If sws Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "There is no worksheet named """ & SRC_SHEET_ID _
            & """ in workbook """ & swb.Name & """!", _
            vbExclamation, PROC_TITLE
        GoTo ProcExit
    End If
    
    ' Reference the source header and data ranges
    ' and determine the source's number of data rows.
    
    Dim shrg As Range, sdrg As Range, RowsCount As Long
    
    With sws.Range("A1").CurrentRegion
        RowsCount = .Rows.Count - 1
        If RowsCount = 0 Then
            MsgBox "No data found in sheet """ & sws.Name & " of workbook """ _
                & swb.Name & """!", vbExclamation, PROC_TITLE
            GoTo ProcExit
        End If
        Set shrg = .Rows(1)
        Set sdrg = .Resize(RowsCount).Offset(1)
    End With
    
    ' Get the source column indices.
    
    Dim scIndices As Variant: scIndices = Application.Match(dhrg, shrg, 0)
    
    ' Reference the destination range.
    
    Dim drg As Range: Set drg = dfrg.Resize(RowsCount)
    
    ' Import values.
    
    Dim sCol As Variant, dCol As Long, dMatchingHeadersCount As Long
    
    ' Check whether there are one or more destination columns.
    If dColumnsCount = 1 Then
        ' Check whether the destination matches one of the source headers.
        If IsNumeric(scIndices) Then ' the header matches
            dMatchingHeadersCount = 1
            If COPY_VALUES_ONLY Then
                drg.Columns(1).Value = sdrg.Columns(scIndices).Value
            Else
                sdrg.Columns(scIndices).Copy Destination:=drg.Columns(1)
            End If
        Else ' the header doesn't match
            MsgBox "There is a single column in the destination sheet """ _
                & dws.Name & """ but its header doesn 't match any headers " _
                & "in the source sheet """ & sws.Name & """!", _
                vbExclamation, PROC_TITLE
            GoTo ProcExit
        End If
    Else
        dMatchingHeadersCount = Application.Count(scIndices)
        ' Check whether there are matching headers.
        If dMatchingHeadersCount > 0 Then ' matching headers found; import values
            For dCol = 1 To dColumnsCount
                sCol = scIndices(dCol)
                If IsNumeric(sCol) Then
                    If COPY_VALUES_ONLY Then
                        drg.Columns(dCol).Value = sdrg.Columns(sCol).Value
                    Else
                        sdrg.Columns(sCol).Copy Destination:=drg.Columns(dCol)
                    End If
                End If
            Next dCol
        Else ' no matching headers
            MsgBox "No header in the destination sheet """ _
                & dws.Name & """ matches the headers in the source sheet """ _
                & sws.Name & """!", vbExclamation, PROC_TITLE
            GoTo ProcExit
        End If
    End If
        
    ' Report how many columns were imported.
        
    MsgBox dMatchingHeadersCount & " column" _
        & IIf(dMatchingHeadersCount = 1, "", "s") & " imported.", _
        vbInformation, PROC_TITLE

ProcExit:
    On Error Resume Next ' prevent endless loop if error in continuation
        ' Close the source file if it wasn't initially open.
        If Not swb Is Nothing Then
            If Not WasSourceFileOpen Then swb.Close SaveChanges:=False
        End If
    On Error GoTo 0
    Exit Sub
' Continue error-handling routine.
ClearError:
    MsgBox "Run-time error [" & Err.Number & "]:" & vbLf & vbLf _
        & Err.Description, vbCritical
    Resume ProcExit
End Sub

